# Concurrent Requests in Multi-tenant App Result in Database Connection Switching and Returning Wrong Data

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am developing a multi-tenant application where the database configuration for each tenant is obtained based on the host of the incoming request. Upon the first request from a tenant, a Sequelize connection is created using the corresponding database configuration. For subsequent requests from the same tenant, the connection is cached to improve performance.

However, I am facing an issue when there are concurrent requests and the function handling the requests performs multiple queries. In such cases, the database connection switches between tenants, leading to incorrect data being returned. This behavior poses a critical security risk as it allows tenants to access each other's data.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
this.app.use(async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  const tenant = req.headers.host === "192.168.3.11:5000" ? "app1" : "app2";
  const sequelize = await getTenantPool(tenant, this.tenantPools);
  const models = await getModels(sequelize.sequelize);
  req.context = {
    models: models,
    sequelize: sequelize.sequelize,
    config: tenant,
    storage: sequelize.storage
  };
  next();
});

export const getTenantPool = async (tenant: string, tenantPools: any) => {
  if (!tenantPools[tenant]) {
    tenantPools[tenant] = await createSequelizeInstance(tenant);
  }
  return tenantPools[tenant];
};

const createSequelizeInstance = async (tenant: string) => {
  // Retrieve the realConfig for the tenant from Cosmos DB or any other source
  const realConfig = await Cosmosclient.getTenantConfig(tenant);
  const config = {
    // Database configuration options
  };
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    // Sequelize configuration options
  );
  return { sequelize: sequelize, config: config, storage: realConfig.azureContainer };
};
```

I suspect that the issue lies in the way the Sequelize connections are managed within the CLS namespace. Despite using caching, concurrent requests seem to share the same connection and cause the data mix-up.

I need guidance on how to ensure that concurrent requests for different tenants use their respective database connections consistently, preventing any data leakage or mixing between tenants.

I have made an attempt to incorporate transactions within my middleware function using the req.context.sequelize.transaction() method provided by Sequelize. The intention was to ensure data integrity and atomicity when executing multiple queries within a single request. However, I noticed that the inclusion of transactions has resulted in a noticeable decrease in application performance.

Despite the potential benefits of using transactions, such as ensuring data consistency and enabling rollback in case of errors, the additional overhead of managing transactional operations has caused an increase in response times and overall slowdown of the application.

Considering the trade-off between data integrity and performance, I am currently seeking alternative approaches that can strike a balance between transactional consistency and maintaining acceptable response times. I would appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to optimize the use of transactions within a multi-tenant environment while minimizing the impact on application performance

Comment: The issue has been fixed, the problem was how i wrote my models,